# JavaScript function doesn't invoke

Tags: javascript, jsp

I'm using .jsp page and in script tag I have a simple function which should be automatically invoked, but it doesn't;

```
<script>
   (function () {
       console.log('test fun');
   })();
</script>
```

The `<script>` is situated in the bottom of `<body>`

Comment: You have to write '$' before start of this function, like $ (function () {
       console.log('test fun');
   })();

Comment: Surely its not included in your html. Try using view source function in your browser

Comment: @Pooja no, it's not jQuery "onload" shorthand, but self-invoking pure JS function.

Answer (score 0):

Is `console` variable available within your self-invoking function? Is it invoking? Try to place there `alert(typeof console)` and check if code is invoked and if console is an `object`.

Comment: Whatever I will put into this function it will not execute.

Comment: Ok, probably I get the source of problem, there's another function in the block (after this one), and if that function get's the error the first one doesn't invoke.